# "There are only 5 non-linear differential equations with fixed singularities."

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, soft-question

In the essay [the pernicious influence of mathematics on philosophy](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Samuel.Le-Fourn/contenu/Reflexions_mathematiques/GianCarloRota.pdf) Gian Carlo Rota makes an offhand remark:

> it is a fact that there are only five non-linear differential equations with fixed singularities

What does this remark mean? In particular what does it mean for a differential equation to have "fixed singularities" and what theorem states that there only 5 such differential equations?

(Is the context of this statement ordinary or partial differential equations?)

Comment: This could be related to Thom's catastrophe theory, normal forms of generic bifurcations.